# If statement in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i do the following:

I have a string

```
something#12
```

I need a regex that will get last two numbers from the string in range from 0 to 19. Note that nothing should be returned if the number after # is greater than 19, i need to ignore letters and special symbols either.

I have tried the following:

```
([0-9]{1}$)|([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}$)
```

but it return last one or two numbers if i have a value greater than 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
/\D[0-1]?\d$/g
```

The `\D` will match any non-digit, `\d` will match any number and you want to optionally (`?`) allow 0 or 1 in front.

Comment: but if i enter something like `text#100` i will get last two zeros. I need to reduce everything that is not in 0..19 range.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `#` before the digit:

```
#([0-9]{1}$)|([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}$)
```

or simpler:

```
#[01]?\d$
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the character before as a non number or a #, someething like

```
[^0-9]([0-9]{1}$)|([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}$)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getThatThing(x) {
  var match = /#([0-9]|[01][0-9])$/.exec("input#1");
  if (match) {
    return match[1];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```